# Jumping position with content update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div that holds many other div elements that are sent from the server. I have a `<select>` that controls the ordering of the elements. Changing this value will trigger the container to be emptied and then new content is sent from the server once again repopulating the container. To clear the container I'm just doing an jquery .empty() (after first detaching some of the elements I need to keep, and restoring those later).

The problem is that this causes the position of the select control to change position and generally move around randomly (due to changes in vertical scrolling). I like the way youtube.com works upon changing of the comment selection from "top comments" to "Newest First". It brings up a spinner and then changes the elements without causing any position or scroll changes. This is similar to what I want to achieve. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Note I already have overflow-y: scroll; within my body of the css.

Comment: You need to include the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem or we can't help you.  Without that this question will be closed.

Comment: You need to provide a working fiddle. Read about that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question with the working example. Otherwise this should be closed as offtopic, and you don't get answers, at least good answers.

Comment: why do i 'need' to provide source code. I'm asking for an approach I re-read and think it's quite clear without source code. a div is being emptied and replaced with new content causing it to jump up and down. I want to understand some approaches like that that youtube use...